# Is there a good site for finding out the location given IP

Tags: ip-address, geolocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Know exact location of IP address](https://superuser.com/questions/225640/know-exact-location-of-ip-address)

Given an IP address, many sites can give an location estimated for where the IP is from. However, the estimation by many sites are not good. For example, this site http://ip-address-lookup-v4.com/ gives an estimation about 50 miles away from my actual place,  based on my IP. I wonder

1. why is that? Is it a problem unsolvable in technology, or just to
   protect privacy?
2. Are there some sites that can provide more accurate estimations?